# Cannot make watermark image for Signature

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I have a logo image that I need to embed in the signature. The logo is such like, a square with 4 parts & each of different part. I want to set watermark on the image, so the text is visible clearly. The code that I use is :

```
                sap.Image = logoSign;
            sap.ImageScale = 0.40f;
            sap.Image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
            //sap.Image.Transparency.SetValue(50, 0);  // Only half image is visible
            sap.GetAppearance().AddImage(logoSign);
```

It is scaled & placed properly. To achieve watermark effect, I add Transparency. When I made its value as (30,0) top left part of the square logo was visible. On making it 50, left half is visible, then I tried with 80, 100, 120, but the full logo is never visible. Elther 1/4th or 1/2 is only visible. The right part that is not showing up has Pink & yellow shades. Surprising is, when I comment the Transparency line, whole logo is visible.

Can anyone help me know, why is it acting like this. And ya, the logo with GIF is only working. PNG &/or JPG logo doesn't show up. Why so ?? I tried other image of jpg also, but no success.

@mkl, RESULTS shown in screenshots 
[image: Screenshots of Signature showing logo with different transparency values]

Thanks

Comment: Please supply a sample PDF illustrating the issue.

Comment: Download http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures and look for the GetTemplate(2) method.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, yes Bruno I have that file and am using that for full reference. I tried giving PDFTemplate lay2 = sap.GetLayer(2);lay2.AddImage(logoSign); The GetLAyer(2) line gives me error "Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I have shown the screenshots of the result with above code. Am not able to make out, what is going wrong where ?

Comment: Strange. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with C# and I've never encountered that problem in Java, so you'll have to ask somebody who knows C#.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to edit the image itself to a particular transparency level with the help of an editor and then use it. why do it in the code.